# Web API Basic Auth inside an MVC app with Identity Auth

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have a `C# MVC` app using `Identity` for its authentication. I now have a need to expose a few things via `Web API` to some of my clients. Instead of building a separate app, project, deployment... I've simply added an `API Controller` to my existing project. To keep things simple for my clients, I've decided to use `Basic Auth`, opting rather to force my clients into using `SSL` connections to my API.

I've followed this very useful tutorial to implement the `Basic Auth` in my API:
http://www.piotrwalat.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-using-message-handlers/

Problem is, that their instructions take over `Auth` for the entire app...

I need my `MVC` app to keep using the `Identity Auth` that it is currently using and hopefully roll my own custom attribute (like `[APIAuthorize]`) so that it only applies to my `API Controller`.

I can probably hack around and try to get this to work, but as this is concerning security, I decided to ask for some pro help on how to best implement this. Specifically, I need to know **1)** what do I do in my `Global.asax` (if anything) as the above URL suggests I do this:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers
          .Add(new BasicAuthMessageHandler(){
             PrincipalProvider = new DummyPrincipalProvider()
           });
        //...
    }
```

But again, this would take over the Authentication to the entire app... **2)** What do I need to do in my custom auth attribute to make all of this work seamlessly.

And of course, if there's a better way to do all of this (without creating a separate app or increasing the implementation difficulty to my clients) then I'm all ears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I us a filter attribute to adorn the actions i wanted to expose to Simple Auth. I cant remember where i got this code from (probably stackoverflow i just don't have the link so i cant claim credit for it)

```
public class BasicHttpAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    { 
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.Length == 0)
            { 
                // Get the header value
                AuthenticationHeaderValue auth = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
                // ensure its schema is correct
                if (auth != null && string.Compare(auth.Scheme, "Basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                {
                    // get the credientials
                    string credentials = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(auth.Parameter));
                    int separatorIndex = credentials.IndexOf(':');
                    if (separatorIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        // get user and password
                        string passedUserName = credentials.Substring(0, separatorIndex);
                        string passedPassword = credentials.Substring(separatorIndex + 1);
                        SimpleAES crypto = new SimpleAES();
                        string userName = crypto.DecryptString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(Constants.SIMPLEUSERNAME));
                        string password = crypto.DecryptString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(Constants.SIMPLEUSERPASSWORD));

                        // validate
                        if (passedUserName == userName && passedPassword == password)
                        {
                            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(userName, "Basic"), new string[] { });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
        }
    }
```

Then i use it as so

```
[BasicHttpAuthorize]
public HttpResponseMessage MyExposedSimpleAuthAction()
```

Comment: I'm completely new to this area and trying to get my head around this stuff. Do you have an example call to an API implementing this filter?...would it just pass the user and pass plain text or encoded somehow? How is the userName and password stored in your configuration manager? And in your example does BasicHttpAuthorize work just standalone or is there more code that is necessary?