# Web Api in MVC site - Implementing MessageHandler in pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, authentication, asp.net-web-api

A few weeks ago I decided to start building an API for my system which is fronted by an MVC portal. I built Web Api capability into my existing MVC site by adding:

```
class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

in my app_start folder, and modifying my Global.asax by adding:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

It worked absolutely fine for calling simple methods in my Values controller either without the `[Authorize]` tag or in my browser by logging in first, but since then I've been reading around implementing basic authentication in asp.net web api and I've found a few examples I've tried to work into my implementation.

I have implemented a code example of a Message Handler I found online to authorize requests to it, at this stage simply comparing an ApiKey header string to one stored locally in my handler class to test it worked.

The handler looks like this:

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
       HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> apiKeyHeaderValues = null;
        if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("ApiKey", out apiKeyHeaderValues))
        {
            var apiKeyHeaderValue = apiKeyHeaderValues.First();

            // ... your authentication logic here ...
            var username = (apiKeyHeaderValue == "12345" ? "Authorised" : "OtherUser");

            var usernameClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username);
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { usernameClaim }, "ApiKey");
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
```

I then added it to my global.asax:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new ApiAuthHandler());
```

Now I took this code in it's entirety from here: https://dzone.com/articles/api-key-user-aspnet-web-api as I'm new to this and lots of implementations of authorisation seemed too complex for my needs/too complex for me to begin my learning with.

I do understand it's flow and from debugging it when receiving a request it does the `ApiKey` comparison correctly and creates the principle. The response however is not correct...and it never reaches the requested api method. I get this response:

**Redirect
To:http://localhost:2242/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2Fvalues with status: 302 Show explanation HTTP/1.1 302 Found**

It is redirecting me to my register method, as the `[Authorize]` tag is meant to, and it's actually returning my `Register.cshtml` in it's entirety. I can't figure out how to ignore this and let the ApiAuthHandler Authorize for me. I'm assuming I need to change something in the MVC pipeline somewhere but I'm not sure what.

Just want to get something very simple working so that I can get my head around it more to explore more complicated API authentication. Any ideas what I've done wrong?

**Edit** added api controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{

    ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    InboundDBContext inboundContext = new InboundDBContext();

    // GET api/<controller>
    [Authorize]
    public string Get()
    {

        return user.Identity.Name;
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {



        return "value";
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your API controller

Comment: Please have a look at this => [Web API Basic Auth inside an MVC app with Identity Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932487/web-api-basic-auth-inside-an-mvc-app-with-identity-auth?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look. @Casey, I added the api controller in an edit

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've had a look and then been reading around the internet all day on this. My api, when authentication in my custom filter fails, still returns 200 and a login page .cshtml. There seems to be no end of "tutorials" on this showing filter code but not properly explaining how to integrate with MVC and have the site authenticated normally via login and web api authenticated exclusively by some other means. Any thoughts would be fantastic

Answer (score 0):

Your WebApiConfig.cs file should look something like this...

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        //add the authorization handler to the pipeline
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new new ApiAuthHandler()());
    }
}
```